# asp.net textbox value not changing

Tags: asp.net, postback

I know its a very common question, but seems like my situation is a bit typical.

I do retrieve the value to be displayed on a `textbox` on page load.

so does not matter how many page loads happen i will get the correct value.

```
 page_load()
    {
        TBName.Text = XYZObject.getName();
    }
```

the thing is: on breakpoint this text shows the correct value, but when i continue and go on webpage, it again shows the old value.

what can be the issue???

Thanks

Comment: can you paste here the html of this textbox?

Comment: First of all - if something is going to be same across page loads, put that in Post.IsPostBack... In current case - do you have any event on the textbox itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was because the textbox was readonly.

Answer (score 6):

No @harish, your situation is not typical at all. In fact, this is the most common situation in asp.net world in my guess.

What you have here is the case when you hit the **breakpoint** and the **ViewState** is loaded i.e. applied to the controls state and you have the correct value entered by the user. What you end up with - is the value you have assigned again in your code block on **PageLoad**.

try this instead:

```
page_load()
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)         
            TBName.Text = XYZObject.getName();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there can be another function like "clearFields()" that is clearing the textbox.
Or getName returns string first but then it is returning empty so that clearing the textbox.

two possibilities I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If I understan correctly, the value stays the same without debugging, but it chages when debugging?
Continue debugging with F10, and show the `TBName.Text` in the Watches window. Then you can see exactly at what row of code the value changes back.